# Link to named frame as new window?

Tags: html

Back in the day, I could make a link with a target like this:

```
<a href="https://example.com/something" target="frameName" />
```

If a frame named `frameName` didn't exist on the page, the link would open in a new window/tab.  That still works today.  Now, add a second link:

```
<a href="https://example.com/somethingElse" target="frameName" />
```

If I click the first link, it opens in a new tab/window.  If I then click the second link, I would expect it to open in that same tab/window that was opened for the first link.  However, this isn't happening.  Instead, the second link opens up in its own new tab/window.

Has this behavior changed?  How can I get the old behavior back?

Comment: This behaviour differs per browser. In Firefox it works as described above, while both IE11 and Edge open a new tab only when a link with a specified [browsing context](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#context) is first clicked and ignore any subsequent clicks on any links specifying an already opened browsing context (for as long as the browsing context remains opened). Whereas Chrome simply opens a new tab and completely disregards any specified browsing contexts.

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra It's not working for me in Firefox either.  Any idea how to get this behavior to work as expected in Chrome?  Any workaround?

Comment: Interesting, my Firefox opens a new tab when clicking on the first link and then opens the second link in the same tab as the first link, unless I change the the links to have differing target values, then it opens both links in their own tabs. Which I believe is exactly the behaviour you are after? I don't have an answer to your questions, I tried using JavaScript `window.open()` with a target specified, but it behaves exactly the same as the links in all browsers.

Comment: The only "workaround" I can think of is using JavaScript to open an "in-page" modal dialog box containing a named `iframe`, and then specifying the name of that `iframe` in the target. That should make sure the pages open in the same `iframe`. But that doesn't really open a new window, and if the reason for wanting a new window is to ensure that the newly loaded page isn't "blocking" the page which opens the link, you'd have to find some way of implementing this modal dialog box in such a manner that it doesn't "block" any of the original page's functionality.

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra My reason for opening a new window is to display secondary content on a second monitor.  :-)  Unfortunately, only game consoles have implemented the whole second-display spec from the W3C.  I think a new window is required.  I suppose I could open a second window with a full iframe, and change that iframe URL.  I think I'll work on that.